# Using preprocessing function of ImageDataGenerator to convert color space

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

Ive encountered a problem that using the preprocessing function of ImageDataGenerator to convert the color space of my image. I tried to convert RGB to CMYK and feed it into the CNN. But the preprocessing function can only return the same shape as the input. For example, the image in RGB mode has a shape(224,224,3), after the convertion, the shape should be converted into (224,224,4). And this seems to be a problem to using the preprocessing function.
Can anyone help?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Lambda
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical, multi_gpu_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras import optimizers
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import os
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as KTF
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import pickle

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"



#cmyk convetion
def rgb_to_cmyk(img_arr):
    aaa = []

    img_arr_min = (255 - img_arr)
    K = np.min(img_arr_min, axis=2)

    C_init = (img_arr_min[:, :, 0])
    M_init = (img_arr_min[:, :, 1])
    Y_init = (img_arr_min[:, :, 2])

    C = C_init - K
    M = M_init - K
    Y = Y_init - K

    aaa.append(C)
    aaa.append(M)
    aaa.append(Y)
    aaa.append(K)
    new_arr = np.array(aaa).transpose(1,2,0)
    return new_arr


#customize function used for color convetion
def myFunc(image):
    image = np.array(image)
    converted_img = rgb_to_cmyk(image)
    converted_img /= 255
    return converted_img




#parameters
batch_size = 32
n_epoch = 150
lr_rate = 0.001



#data augementation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = None,
                                   rotation_range = 30,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   preprocessing_function=myFunc)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = None,
                                  preprocessing_function=myFunc)



with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # load data
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train_dir',
                                                        target_size=(224,224),
                                                        color_mode='rgb',
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        class_mode='categorical')

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_dir',
                                                      target_size=(224,224),
                                                      color_mode='rgb',
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      class_mode='categorical')








#initialize the model
model = Sequential()

# Conv Block 1
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(224,224,1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 3
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 4
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# Conv Block 5
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

# FC layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(101, activation='softmax'))






network = model

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=lr_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
network.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
network.summary()



# train
history_callback = network.fit_generator(train_generator,
                      steps_per_epoch=2000,
                      epochs=n_epoch,
                      validation_data=test_generator,
                      validation_steps=800, verbose=2)
                      #use_multiprocessing=False)




all_history = history_callback.history
pickle.dump(all_history, open('save_dir/results', 'wb'), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras only works with rgb or grayscale images.
For example a snippet from the `array_to_img()` method:

```
if x.shape[2] == 4:
    # RGBA
    return pil_image.fromarray(x.astype('uint8'), 'RGBA')
elif x.shape[2] == 3:
    # RGB
    return pil_image.fromarray(x.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
elif x.shape[2] == 1:
    # grayscale
```

Thus you have to convert CMYK images to RGB first.